# 大阪から東京までに泳ごうとしたけど、途中で道に迷います。Does this sound natural/correct?

Tags: translation

大阪から東京までに泳ごうとしたけど、途中で道に迷います。
My translation:[(I implied) tried to swim from Osaka to Tokyo, but got lost on the way.]
   I haven't saw (までに) used like this before, so I'm not sure if I am using it right in
   this sentence. Is there another way to make this sound/read right?

Answer (score 5):

> 「[大阪]{おおさか}から[東京]{とうきょう}までに[泳]{およ}ごうとしたけど、[途中]{とちゅう}で[道]{みち}に[迷]{まよ}います。」

The first thing I would earnestly like to sugggest is that you take the bullet train instead.

A couple of other things I would like to point out are:

> It is 「大阪から東京**まで**」, not 「大阪から東京**までに**」. You have no choice there.

「までに」 expresses a temporal limitation, not anything spatial.

「8[時]{じ}**までに**[来]{き}てください。」 = "Please come by 8 o'clock."

> Change the tense of 「迷います」 to 「迷った」 to go with the past-tense verb phrase 「泳ごうとした」.

In all honesty, I do not even know if one could say 「道に迷う」 when talking about swimming in the ocean .  I know that it does not sound too strange to my Japanese ears as we do not really have a word for it.  It sure adds humor to the statement, so let us keep it.

> We now have 「大阪から東京まで泳ごうとしたけど、途中で道に迷った。」

To make it sound one-step more natural, I would suggest the sentence:

> 「東京から大阪まで泳いで**いこう**としたけど、途中で道に迷った。」

Finally, an even more natural way to say it would be:

> 「東京から大阪まで泳いでいこうとしたけど、途中で道に迷って**しまった**。」

Comment: Thanks:)「迷った」 I'm surprised that I missed that one myself,also I got 「道に迷う」from a dictionary so it might just be obscure.

Comment: In this case, I'd personally use 東京**にかけて** instead of まで.

Comment: You can also use 方向【ほうこう】を見【み】失【うしな】ってしまった instead (literary "lost direction"), if you want to avoid using 道.

Comment: +1 for 方向を見失う : I might understand 「道に迷う」in this case as "to be lost *before* swimming (somewhere between your house and the seashore)".

Answer (score 5):

I would change 道 for 方面 or possibly 方向 or even better say 迷子になった. There is no road in the water.